# Rails + CarrierWave + RMagick not logging errors..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

Using carrier wave to upload a pdf document via CarrierWave.  Then using RMagick to save the first page of the pdf as a thumbnail.jpg.  I have this working correctly in my development environment (Mac OS X 10.9), however its failing in production (Nginx + Unicorn on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

It appears that the upload completes successfully, based on watching the upload percentage in the browser status bar.  However, something errors in the processing, and I get Rails error page.  The problem is, there is nothing in my production.log.

I get the following in unicorn.log:

```
I, [2013-12-12T01:22:55.232431 #2935]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2013-12-12T01:22:55.246992 #2932]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
E, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.666715 #2929] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:2935 timeout (31s > 30s),     killing
E, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.676250 #2929] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 2935 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.676382 #2929]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.681087 #3502]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=3502
I, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.681399 #3502]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
    SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
    This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
    provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
    cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
    future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

    Called from: /home/deployer/apps/______/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
```

And this in my nginx error.log

```
2013/12/12 01:26:00 [error] 2597#0: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ###.###.###.###, server: ___.org, request: "POST /admin/explores HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock:/admin/explores", host: "___.org", referrer: "https://___.org/admin/explores/new"
```

Not sure how to get a better error description of what's going on.  Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Ruby 1.9.3 + Rails 3.2.9

Answer (score 0):

The line `E, [2013-12-12T01:26:00.666715 #2929] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:2935 timeout (31s > 30s),     killing` from your `unicorn.log` tells you the problem: you have a timeout. Increase unicorn's timeout to 60 seconds by setting `timeout 60` in your `unicorn.rb`. More information: http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-timeout